# Hierarchical git config

Tags: git

On my personal machine I have set my personal email address in my global git config.

```
$ git config --global --get user.email
steve@personal.com
```

However, I also have my company's code checked out, and as such, I need to configure git with my company's email address.

```
$ cd corp/project
$ git config --local --get user.email
steve@corp.com
```

Sometimes, however, when cloning a repo I forget to override my email address, and so I commit using my personal email address.

It would be possible to remove my global git config, thereby preventing me from committing in any repo before setting `user.email` in the local git config.

This is a bit of a pita though, and in an ideal world I would be able to set a hierarchical git config so that repos under a certain subdirectory (or some other means of working out which config applies) use the most specific setting therein.

Something like the following:

```
~/
|
+--- .gitconfig               # sets personal email address
|
+--- src/
     |
     +--- project/            # ~/.gitconfig email address applies 
     |    
     +--- corp/
          |
          +--- .git/config    # sets corp email address
          |
          +--- project/       # corp/.git/config email address applies
```

AFAIK currently this isn't natively possible with git, it would require a new level of config which sits between global and local

Is there a way for me to achieve what I'm looking for here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not supported yet, however as of git 2.8 (Mar '16) you can disable global user config as follows:

```
git config --global user.useConfigOnly true
```

That way git will never let you commit until you set an email in your local config. You can think of a script to fetch your global settings and copy to local config for a quick solution though.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout out [this great post](https://orrsella.com/2013/08/10/git-using-different-user-emails-for-different-repositories/) on [git hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) by Orr Sella, specifically for e-mail use. He completely foregoes a global config, and uses a hook to prevent a clone with no config available:

```
EMAIL=$(git config user.email)
if [ -z "$EMAIL" ]; then
    # user.email is empty
    echo "ERROR: [pre-commit hook] Aborting commit because user.email is missing. Configure user.email for this repository by running: '$ git config user.email name@example.com'. Make sure not to configure globally and use the correct email."
    exit 1
else
    # user.email is not empty
    exit 0
fi
```

The way to use this is in the post. You could refine this to look for a local config in the repository root, check for e-mail (using grep even) and if it doesn't exists use the global. Something like

```
EMAIL = $(grep user.email $GIT_DIR/config)
if [[ $? ]]; then 
    EMAIL = $(git config user.email)
    exit 0
fi
EMAIL = $(EMAIL##*user.email* )
```

**GIT_DIR** is guaranteed to be the repository root when the hook runs.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK git itself does not support more than per-repo and global identity.

I archived similar stuff by using a cd hook in `zsh`:

```
# ~/.zshrc
# call this function after cd-ing into a directory
__zsh-on-cd () {
if git ls-files &>/dev/null ; then
    if [[ "$PWD" =~ 'Company' ]]; then
        echo "setting git to use company identity"
        git config user.name "John Doe"
        git config user.email "doe@company.com"
    else
        echo "setting git to use personal identity"
        git config user.name "johndoes"
        git config user.email "me@personal.domain"
    fi
fi
}

chpwd_functions=(${chpwd_functions[@]} "__zsh-on-cd")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right in the assumption that this is **not natively supported** by git at the moment. [[1]](https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration)

I think the most simple workaround is to write a script you use to create/clone repositories. You could then set an (git) alias (e.g. `git myinit` | `git myclone`) which asks you whether the project is personal or not and which sets the email address correspondingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use git hooks: pre-commit to checkout your local config and throw an error.

```
# A git hook to make sure user.email and user.mail in repository  exists before committing

repository_email=$(git config --local --get user.email)
repository_name=$(git config --local --get user.name)

if [ -z "$repository_email" ] || [ -z "$repository_name" ]; then
    # user.email is empty
    echo "ERROR: [pre-commit hook] Aborting commit because user.email or user.name is missing. Configure them for this repository."
    exit 1
else  
    # user.email is not empty
    exit 0
fi
```